# pixelated text inside subviews in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

[image: Pixelated text]

The text is pixelated when I try using iPhone 11 Pro Max simulator, it has less problem with iPhone 11 Pro simulator, and no problem with iPhone SE simulator.

Information disclose:

- I added boarder to the top block of text using

```swift
chartLegendLabel.sizeToFit()
let textWidth = chartLegendLabel.frame.width
let textHeight = chartLegendLabel.frame.height
chartLegendLabel.edgesToSuperview(insets: TinyEdgeInsets(top: barContainerContainer.frame.height - textHeight - 16, left: barContainerContainer.frame.width - textWidth - 16, bottom: 4, right: 4) )
chartLegendLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
chartLegendLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
```

Other text I just arranged using Interface Builder. Auto resizing is switched on.

Thanks a lot for your help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added this line `layer.shouldRasterize = false` in my shadow function (which adds shadow to the text's superview) and everything worked out.

```
static func shadow(in layer:CALayer){
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width:1,height:5)
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
        layer.shadowRadius = 10
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.shouldRasterize = false
}
```